# \poemtitlenotitle in verse package

Tags: verse

[`poemscol`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/poemscol) has a `\poemtitlenotitle` macro which according to the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/poemscol/poemscol.pdf):

> "does not produce a title in the text, but sets its argument in the table of contents and in the notes. Usually you use the first line as the moral equivalent of a title."

I have a lot of unnamed poems. Is it possible to do the same action, using `verse`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Even though the intent of your question is fairly clear to me (at least that's what I think), you can make it much easier to help you if you can show us an example document that reproduces the issue (a so-called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)). I would be happy to have a look at your problem, but I'm not keen on guessing what your document setup looks like only to find out later that I guessed wrong and wrote an answer that does not help you at all.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no equivalent in the `verse` package but here is something based on the general `\addcontentsline` macro.

```
%\documentclass{...}
\usepackage{verse}
\newcommand*{\poemtitlenotitle}[1]{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}}
% ...
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
% ...
\poemtitle{Poem title}
\begin{verse}
A line \\
\end{verse}

\poemtitlenotitle{Title in ToC}
\begin{verse}
First line \\
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

Change the `section` argument in the `\addcontentsline` to match the indentation of other poem titles in the ToC.